# MASM Adding up the sum of elements in an array

Tags: arrays, assembly, sum, masm, irvine32

I'm just trying to write a simple program that takes in x amount of integers from a user, have the user enter them, then use a subroutine to calculate the sum of the array and print out the sum.

I want to pass the address of the array in EAX and the number of array elements into EBX.

```
;Lab 4

title Template Lab4 Adder

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc ;32bit assembler

.data
theansweris DWORD ?
welcometoadder BYTE "Welcome to adder",0dh,0ah,0
howmanynumbers BYTE "How many numbers would you like to add?:",0dh,0ah,0
enteranumber BYTE "Enter a Number:",0dh,0ah,0
youentered BYTE "You entered:",0dh,0ah,0
thesumis BYTE "The sum of the numbers is:",0dh,0ah,0
space BYTE " ",0dh,0ah,0
readStr    DB  50 DUP(?) ;allocates 50 BYTES WITH ?
var1 DWORD ?
testz DWORD 0
sum         BYTE    11 DUP(?), " is the sum.", 0dh, 0ah
numArray    DWORD   ?
numElts     DWORD   100
num         DWORD   ?
resultLbl   BYTE    "Results", 0

.code
main PROC
    call Clrscr
    mov edx, OFFSET welcometoadder
    call WriteString
    ;mov     ecx, 100                   ; loop count (size of array)
    ;lea     ebx, numElts               ; get address of the array
    mov edx, OFFSET howmanynumbers
    call WriteString

    mov edx,OFFSET enteranumber
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov edx,OFFSET youentered
    call WriteString
    mov ebx,eax
    mov edx,ebx
    call WriteInt
    mov edx, OFFSET space
    call WriteString
    ;mov ebx,edx
    mov ecx,ebx
    lea ebx,NumElts

LOOP1:
        mov edx, OFFSET enteranumber
        call WriteString
        mov edx, OFFSET space
        call WriteString
        call ReadInt
        mov     [ebx], eax                  ; store in the array            
        add     ebx, 4                      ; get address of next array elt
        cmp ecx,0
        je LOOP2
        loop    LOOP1                       ; repeat nbrElts times
LOOP2:
call DumpRegs
;mov eax,[ebx]                  ;get the num
;add edx,eax                    ;increase the sum
;add ebx,4                      ;next array element
;loop LOOP2

;    CALL ADDER

;ADDER PROC
;    add bx, cx
;    add bx, cx
;    add ax, bx
    ;mov edx, OFFSET thesumis
    ;call WriteString
;    RET
;ADDER ENDP

    exit
    main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't reserve any memory to store the array!
All you wrote is:

```
numElts DWORD   100

mov     ecx, ebx
lea     ebx, NumElts
LOOP1:
```

Change the definition to:

```
numElts DWORD   100 dup(?)
```

Extra. Within *LOOP1* the extra test for ECX is useless!

```
cmp     ecx, 0      <<<< remove
je      LOOP2       <<<< remove
loop    LOOP1
LOOP2:
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to use some kind of stack operation and loop in the adder subprocedure. ECX is loop counter so the first part should work. You'll need to reset the loop counter before the subproc is called though.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove some irrelevant meta commentary.  Regarding the 50 reputation requirement to comment, you can [read more about it on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/50-reputation-points-to-make-comments)

Answer (score -5):

```
ADDER PROC
add eax,[ebx]
```

something like that i guess